# C# DataContract with non-constant variable names

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON file using a data contract in C#, however I have a problem since member names are not always constant, but the structure is.

Take this JSON for example (created by texture packer):

```
{
    "frames": {
        "frame-abc":
        {
            "frame": {"x":41,"y":2,"w":256,"h":256},
            "rotated": false,
            "trimmed": false,
            "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":256,"h":256},
            "sourceSize": {"w":256,"h":256}
        },
        "someframe":
        {
            "frame": {"x":2,"y":2,"w":37,"h":382},
            "rotated": false,
            "trimmed": false,
            "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":37,"h":382},
            "sourceSize": {"w":37,"h":382}
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about creating a DataContract for it?
Notice "frame-abc" and "someframe" have the exact same structure, but different names.
So I would like to have a class that has an array of frames (each frame has frame, rotated, trimmed, spriteSourceSize and sourceSize elements), that will be loaded from this JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't create `DataContract` for it. But with the help of [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and Linq, you can do:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var frameDict = jObj["frames"].Children()
               .OfType<JProperty>()
               .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value.ToObject<Frame>());


public class Rect
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
}

public class SSize
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
}

public class Frame
{
    public Rect frame { get; set; }
    public bool rotated { get; set; }
    public bool trimmed { get; set; }
    public Rect spriteSourceSize { get; set; }
    public SSize sourceSize { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try JSON.NET. Any chance you can translate that to C#? Also, I need to maintain the order in the JSON file, I understand dictionary will cause me to lose it.

Comment: a) It is already c# b) if your are not interested in frame-name you can replace `.ToDictionary(...)` with `.Select(p => p.Value.ToObject<Frame>()).ToList();`

Comment: It doesn't recognize the method `OfType()`

Comment: Have you included `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: yes. It recognizes it all up until `Children()` but then it says that `JEnumerable` doesn't have a `OfType` member function.

Comment: And it doesn't appear in JSON.NET documentation either... http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

Comment: hmm... I see it is a member of IEnumerable, which is the parent of JEnumerable... I'm using mono, maybe it's not implemented there?

Comment: @tbkn23 you can also try `Cast` instead of `OfType`

Comment: Ok, I manually iterated every one of the children and called `ToObject<Frame>()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Newtonsoft's Json.net `JObject` class to deserialize your entire structure.

Once you have that, you can iterate through the children of 'frames'.

For each child, you can create a new `JsonReader` object and deserialize from that point down.

Answer (score 0):

There's an obvious `FrameInfo` class you can define (with properties frame, rotated, etc).  Then you can deserialize a `Dictionary<String, FrameInfo>` from the "frames" property.  Obviously this gives you a `Dictionary` and not an `Array`, so you lose order information.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Actually, it is... The frame order is important. Also, how do I deserialize a dictionary?